# Select count of same entries in different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, count

I got 3 tables

```
| ID   | Name   |
|:---- |:------:| 
| 1    | Brie   | 
| 2    | Ray    | 
| 3    | James  | 

Table2

| ID   | Q_id   | Q_no  | ans |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|----:|
| 1    | 2304.  | 1     |  A  |
| 1    | 2304.  | 2     |  A  |
| 1    | 2305.  | 1     |  C  |
| 2    | 2304.  | 2     |  A  |
| 2    | 2305.  | 1     |  C  |
| 3    | 2304.  | 1     |  A  |
| 3    | 2305.  | 2     |  D  |

Table3
 | Q_id   | Q_no  | correct_ans |
 |:------:| -----:|------------:|
 | 2304.  | 1     |  A          |
 | 2304.  | 2     |  B          |
 | 2305.  | 1     |  C          |
 | 2305.  | 2     |  D          |
```

**I need to print a table with ID, name and count of ans in table 2 where ans matches with correct answer from table 3**

```
| ID   | Name   | ans_count  |
|:---- |:------:| ----------:|
| 1    | Brie   |   2        |
| 2    | Ray    |   1        |
| 3    | James  |   2        |
```

```
Select t1.ID, Name, count(t2.ans) as ans_count
from Table1 t1
join Table2 t2 on t1.ID=t2.ID
join Table3 t3 on t2.Q_id=t3.Q_id
where t2.ans=t3.correct.ans and t2.q_no=t3.q_no
group by t1.ID
order by t1.ID
```

Where am I doing it wrong? Sorry I am new to SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always link the tables, with all colums that match

AND the GROUP By should contain all columns that have no aggregation function

```
SELECT t1.ID,t1.`Name`,COUNT(*) as correct_answers
FROM table1 t1 
  JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
  JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.`Q_id` = t3.`Q_id` AND  t2.`Q_no` = t3.`Q_no`
WHERE t3.`correct_ans` = t2.`ans`
GROUP BY t1.ID,t1.`Name`
order by t1.ID
```

| ID | Name | correct_answers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Brie | 2 |
| 2 | Ray | 1 |
| 3 | James | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4hlSRLG4)

Comment: Hey, thank you so much! It worked. I have two follow up questions could you please help me out?

Comment: 1)I have another table having columns Class(extra col from from t1) and Q_id(from t2) along with a new column subject_name. While I am joining this table4, do I need to write all the columns from all the tables that match?

Comment: 2) Since each q_id corresponds to different subject_name, while counting correct answers respective to the subject (correct_ans_maths/correct_ans_history etc) where do I exactly write the where clause in the query since its different from different subject_name?

Comment: sql strugels and produces an error, when it finds the same filed like ID in more than one table, also we recommend to write all columns, because when you read the query in one year, you need to understand what you tried to achieve with the query a SELECT * is not good and with your design ever worse

Comment: Yeah, I should have written but the table1 got like 7-8 columns and there are 4 tables that need to be joined

Comment: you never need all columns in my experience, as you have a goal and you  know which columns are need to achieve it. if one or hundred, you still need to write all down. so that other can understand what you are trying#

Comment: Thank you for your insight. Can I write the where condition write after count? I need to count different entries for having different conditions.

Comment: when you want to qury the count you need HAVING else you can add more condition in the where clause, or if you want to exclude you can add conditions in the ON clause, you need to test the results

Answer (score 0):

Its still not clear what you are after, but this corrects the obvious issue with the query.

```sql
Select t1.ID, Name, count(*) as ans_count
from Table1 t1
join Table2 t2 on t1.ID=t2.ID
join Table3 t3 on t2.Q_id=t3.Q_id
where t2.ans=t3.correct.ans
group by t1.ID, t1.Name  ///<---------------
order by t1.ID
```

I think you need to group by Id and Name

Comment: Basically I want a count of how many answers they got correct? Hope I am making sense

Comment: Did you try it.

Comment: Then please tick the answer to indicate that its the correct answer